# Javascript function control in callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I am not sure I am fully getting javascript. I have three functions which call each other so one, two and three..  but I don't want three to run if condition in two is true.  For some reason it keeps running function three. How can I ensure function three doesn't run based on the condition in function 2.  Sorry if this is already answered somewhere but I couldn't find it.. i have looked and looked. think my head is about to explode.. thank you.

This is basic example of how I configured my code:

```
gpio = require("rpi-gpio");

gpio.setup(35, gpio.DIR_OUT, dooropen);  //motor will raise the door
//gpio.setup(37, DIR_OUT, CLOSEDOOR); //motor will lower the door
gpio.setup(40, gpio.DIR_IN, TopHall);  //Top Hall Effect Sensor
gpio.setup(38, gpio.DIR_IN, BottomHall); // Bottom Halle Effect Sensor


function dooropen(err, value){
  if (err) {
    console.log('Some type of error');
  } else {
  //first check door is closed on gpio 38
  //use function doorClosedCallback which receives (err, value) arguments from DOORCLOSED gpio pin
    gpio.read(38, BottomHall);
  }
}

function BottomHall(err, value) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error checking BottomHall.');
  } else if (value === true) {
    console.log('Door is not closed.');
    return;
    } else {
    gpio.write(35, true, TopHall);
    console.log('Door will open now.');
  }
}

function TopHall(err, value) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Door open failed to start.', err);
    return;
  } else {
    function readInput() {
    gpio.read(38, function(err, value) {
        console.log('The value is ' + value);
    });
    }
    var doorinvteralopen = setInterval(function(){
      gpio.read(40, function(err, value) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Door start failed.', err);
          return;
        } else if (value === true) {
              console.log('Door not yet open, keep the motor running.');
        } else {
          clearInterval(doorinvteralopen);
          console.log('Door is finally open.');
          gpio.write(35, false, function(err) {
            if (err) {console.log('Error stopping the door motor.', err);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
}

//CHANGE I WILL ADD TO ABOVE
function TopHall(err, value) {
     gpio.read(38, function(err, value){
       if(value !== false){
       console.log('No Hall Effect Sensors available, com stopped');
       return;
      }
     });
     var doorinvteralopen = setInterval(function(){...
```

Comment: You've removed all the relevant parts from your code. We need to see how you set `twoParam`. Please show your *actual* code and example input.

Comment: Juhana I added my actual program..

Comment: That's better, but now it's unclear which part of the code is not working. Please describe what you expect the output of the code to be and what it actually is. Include the input you're getting from gpio.

Comment: I do not want function TopHall to run any of its content if function BottomHall value is equal to True.  For some function TopHall runs the setinterval(function) 3 times and spits out "door is open" to the console.  Basically, I am doing error checking to not do anything if I don't have a reading on pin 38.  Hopefully I described this correctly.  Thanks

Comment: @Juhana  - I added a snippet of code at the bottom of my original code above.  I believe this will correct my issues, hopefully.  Won't be able to test till later tonight but wanted to see what you think?  Formatting will be double checked too.  thanks.

Answer (score -3):

If I understand your question correctly, this might be solved with a simple else in function two, making it look something like this:

```
function two(twoParam) {
  if (twoParam === true) {
    return;
  }

  else {
    var threeParam = ...;
    three(threeParam);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have added my actual code that works to open the door if everything is perfect.. I am trying to do some error checking just in case my door gets stuck..  so it should return and stop running anything past the else if in function bottomhall but it doesn't.. thanks..